# JApplets: removing top and bottom bands

Tags: java, applet

In my JApplet, by default there is a band at the top and the bottom

I Guess:

Top : Menu

1) How can I control the content and the actions
2) can it be removed

Bottom : Application information message (Loading ...)

1) Can I control what is displayed 
2) Can it be removed

If anybody has a good reference/tutorial to Japplets it would be welcome (I'm really rushed by time on this one :P)

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using the AppletViewer for testing.  An (J)Applet that is embedded in a web page has no components that are not added by the programmer.

As far as the programmer defined actions go, see JApplet.setJMenu(JMenu).